# Atom Editor, Set default syntax for erb files: HTML(Rails) over HTML(Ruby - erb)

Tags: atom-editor

I just spent the last hour going through Atom forums looking for an answer for this. Has anyone figured it out yet?

Comment: I haven't seen such packages.
As temporarily solution you can try to use 'set-syntax' package. With this package you can easily change syntax with a shortcut.

Answer (score 5):

```
core:
    customFileTypes:
      "text.html.ruby": [
        "erb"
      ]
```

Add above to config.cson and restart atom.